# No sound issue on Ubuntu 20.04 with Huawei D14 Laptop

Tags: sound, huawei

I recently installed Ubuntu in my laptop and I have the issue that the sound does not recognize the audio output of the laptop and appears as "Dummy Output". Extra information:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [sofhdadsp      ]: sof-hda-dsp - sof-hda-dsp
                      HUAWEI-NBLB_WAX9N-M1010-NBLB_WAX9N_PCB_B2

$ lsmod | grep snd
snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp    24576  0
snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common    20480  1 snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_soc_hdac_hdmi      36864  1 snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_soc_dmic           16384  1
snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl    16384  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    98304  1 snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
soundwire_intel        40960  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_pci            20480  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof               131072  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_ext_core       32768  4 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    49152  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_core          286720  7 soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_dmic,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_compress           28672  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          53248  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       28672  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         147456  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_hda_core           94208  9 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               114688  11 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    94208  13 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 huawei_wmi,snd_sof

$ inxi -SA
System:
  Host: ivan-laptop Kernel: 5.13.0-27-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.13.0-27-generic 

$ modprobe --show-depends snd_hda_intel
insmod /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/soundcore.ko 
install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; } 
insmod /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-timer.ko 
install /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; } 
insmod /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/core/snd-hwdep.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-hda-core.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-codec.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-intel-sdw-acpi.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/hda/snd-intel-dspcfg.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/5.13.0-27-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-intel.ko 


$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 2: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: is pulseaudio running? `pulseaudio --check` any return?

Comment: might help : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451232/no-sound-on-huawei-14s-with-ubuntu-22-10/1451233#1451233

Comment: I had this issue. Try pipewire. See here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1449349/no-sound-on-ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-msi-ge76-laptop https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-pipewire-on-ubuntu-linux