# No sound on Ubuntu 22.10 Kinetic - MSI GE76 Laptop

Tags: nvidia, sound, alsa, intel, 22.10

I have a new laptop, a Raider GE76.  I installed Ubuntu on it and everything is working except the sound presently.

I only have dummy sound as an output option.

I've tried some solutions on the web but none have worked.

- I've tried adding entries to GRUB
- I've tried installing the SOF binaries (v2.2.4)
- I've tried tweaking the driver options in `modprobe/alsa.conf`
- I've tried switching to the legacy driver

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html

[Sound card not detected - Ubuntu 20.04 - sof-audio-pci](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243369/sound-card-not-detected-ubuntu-20-04-sof-audio-pci)

I'd appreciate any suggestions/troubleshooting on getting the sound to work.

`aplay -l` output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC274 Analog [ALC274 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 12: HDMI 6 [HDMI 6]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 13: HDMI 7 [HDMI 7]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 14: HDMI 8 [HDMI 8]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 15: HDMI 9 [HDMI 9]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 16: HDMI 10 [HDMI 10]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 17: HDMI 11 [HDMI 11]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 11: HDMI 5 [HDMI 5]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio` output:

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller [8086:51c8] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller [1462:1324]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
--
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GA106 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:228e] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1324]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

`lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel` output:

```
snd_hda_intel          53248  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         172032  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core          118784  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_pcm               159744  11 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_sof_utils,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd                   114688  14 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

`sudo alsa force-reload` output:

```
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-sof-pci-intel-tgl snd-sof-intel-hda-common snd-sof-intel-hda snd-sof-pci snd-sof-xtensa-dsp snd-sof snd-sof-utils snd-soc-hdac-hda snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-acpi-intel-match snd-soc-acpi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-intel-sdw-acpi snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-sof-pci-intel-tgl snd-sof-intel-hda-common snd-sof-intel-hda snd-sof-pci snd-sof-xtensa-dsp snd-sof snd-sof-utils snd-soc-hdac-hda snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-acpi-intel-match snd-soc-acpi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-intel-sdw-acpi snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer.
```

Editing GRUB with:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"
```

results in:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller [8086:51c8] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller [1462:1324]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
--
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GA106 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:228e] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1324]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

However, sound still doesn't work.

Changed the GRUB entry based on previous error message from:

```
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1"
```

because it threw an error message:

```
fafnir /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[3129]: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.19.0-28-generic root=ZFS=UbuntuZFS/root ro quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0 vt.handoff=1
```

Now `syslog` reports:

```
Syslog entries with revised grub driver entry:

Jan  8 17:02:10 fafnir kernel: [    9.404460] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Jan  8 17:02:10 fafnir kernel: [    9.404638] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
Jan  8 17:02:10 fafnir kernel: [    9.404816] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
Jan  8 17:02:10 fafnir kernel: [    9.404872] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
Jan  8 17:02:10 fafnir kernel: [    9.404877] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
```

Alsa report - http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=9bcc15cd8d2a29a5e0f3b60e2b1f84a6e95ed7ae

---

```
$ inxi -SMA
System:
  Host: fafnir Kernel: 5.19.0-28-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME
    v: 43.1 Distro: Ubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Micro-Star product: Raider GE76 12UE v: REV:1.0
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-17K4 v: REV:1.0 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: E17K4IMS.209 date: 09/13/2022
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio
    driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GA106 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-28-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.58 running: yes
```

I followed this guide as well: no joy

https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/

Comment: Do you have the correct nVidia driver installed? From Ubuntu repository?

Comment: Nvidia-driver-525 is installed from the repos.  Additional Drivers says it is the recommended driver. Card is GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q

Comment: I would then think sound would be using nVidia driver, not the Intel one. But I do not have nVidia to see details.

Comment: I think NVIDIA sound would go out HDMI.  I haven't tested HDMI, but the onboard speakers, mic etc. comes from the Realtek/Intel driver.

I did a hardware probe and this appears to be card installed:
https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:8086-51c8-1462-1324

How do I configure these drivers?

Comment: yes, kinetic, sorry. I have other machines with jammy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this guide: [How to install PipeWire on Ubuntu Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-pipewire-on-ubuntu-linux)

Sound (speakers only) is restored. No microphone, however. When I plug in a USB speaker with microphone, it shows up in the sound settings.

I reverted/taken out the following changes:

- `/etc/defaults/grub` changes:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
  #GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"
  #GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1"
  ```
- `alsa-base.conf` changes. The below entries were recommended by various sites:

  ```
  #options snd-usb-audio index=-2
  #options snd-hda-intel model=generic
  #options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=0
  #options snd-hda-intel model=auto
  #options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
  ```

I had also disabled (and then re-enabled) secure boot (no change on the problem).

Once I backed out all the above changes, full sound system was detected:

[image: Sound control panel]