# Ubuntu 22.04, no sound from speakers

Tags: sound, 22.04, alsa, speakers

I have a new laptop, HP Zbook firefly, which has Ubuntu 22.04 installed.  This is the only OS on the computer, and I've never had any other versions.

The sound card is an Intel Alder Lake.

There is no sound from the internal speakers.  The internal microphone works, external headphones work, and if I plug in to a monitor over the USB-C then the sound from the monitor works.  The internal speakers do not work.

In the system sound settings, the speaker is listed as "Speaker sof-hda-dsp".   If I play a video (in Firefox or Chrome), the blue output bar flashes as sound plays.  But no sound actually comes out of the speakers.

[system sound settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFiRT.png)

The sound apparently works just fine -- unless I'm trying to play it from the internal speakers.

I checked inside the BIOS, turned off the speakers, and booted up.  Then the only option for output was "dummy".  Then re-started into the BIOS and turned the speakers back on inside the BIOS, then booted up, and the Speakers were there again.  And they still didn't work.

In Alsa Mixer, the sound for the speakers is set to maximum, and says 00 (unmuted).

[Alsa Mixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnVEB.png)

I tried the [Ubuntu Sound Troubleshooting Procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) and none of those suggestions fixed or discovered the problem.  The `killall` command followed by either `pulseaudio --start` or by a reboot did nothing.  The command from Step 3 generates a ton of output, but I believe the most important part of the output is this:

```
!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    5.15.0-69-generic
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     k5.15.0-69-generic
Library version:    1.2.6.1
Utilities version:  1.2.6


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------

snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp (card 0)
snd_usb_audio (card 1)


!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

PipeWire:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pipewire)
      Running - Yes

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------

 0 [sofhdadsp      ]: sof-hda-dsp - sof-hda-dsp
                      HP-HPZBookFirefly16inchG9MobileWorkstationPC--8ABB
 1 [C920           ]: USB-Audio - HD Pro Webcam C920
                      HD Pro Webcam C920 at usb-0000:00:14.0-4.2, high speed


!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller [8086:51c8] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8abb]
```

Running pavucontrol does nothing the system sound settings can't do.  The rest of the steps in the troubleshoot are about generating documentation or only pertinent to specific cases that don't match my own.

None of the quick fixes or solutions on any of the previously asked questions did anything to resolve the issue.

I'm new to Linux and not sure what info is needed to address this.  Below is some info that might be helpful:

Output of `aplay -l`

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDA Digital (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Output of `lspci -nnk`

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller [8086:51c8] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8abb]
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
```

Result of `also force-reload`

```
$ sudo alsa force-reload
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-dummy snd-hrtimer snd-soc-skl-hda-dsp snd-soc-intel-hda-dsp-common snd-soc-hdac-hdmi snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-soc-dmic snd-hda-codec-generic snd-sof-pci-intel-tgl snd-sof-intel-hda-common snd-sof-intel-hda snd-sof-pci snd-sof-xtensa-dsp snd-sof snd-soc-hdac-hda snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-acpi-intel-match snd-soc-acpi snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-intel-sdw-acpi snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer snd-hda-scodec-cs35l41-spi snd-hda-scodec-cs35l41-i2c snd-hda-scodec-cs35l41 snd-soc-cs35l41-lib (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hrtimer snd-soc-skl-hda-dsp snd-soc-intel-hda-dsp-common snd-soc-hdac-hdmi snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-soc-dmic snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-seq-dummy snd-hrtimer snd-soc-skl-hda-dsp snd-soc-intel-hda-dsp-common snd-soc-hdac-hdmi snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-soc-dmic snd-hda-codec-generic snd-sof-pci-intel-tgl snd-sof-intel-hda-common snd-sof-intel-hda snd-sof-pci snd-sof-xtensa-dsp snd-sof snd-soc-hdac-hda snd-hda-ext-core snd-soc-acpi-intel-match snd-soc-acpi snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-intel snd-intel-dspcfg snd-intel-sdw-acpi snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer snd-hda-scodec-cs35l41-spi snd-hda-scodec-cs35l41-i2c snd-hda-scodec-cs35l41 snd-soc-cs35l41-lib.
```

Contents of `/proc/asound/modules`

```
$ cat /proc/asound/modules
 0 snd_hda_intel
```

Some other places with a similar issue, whose "solutions" did not work for my issue:

- https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/701751
- [No sound on Ubuntu 22.10 Kinetic - MSI GE76 Laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1449349/no-sound-on-ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-msi-ge76-laptop)
- [No sound in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS after upgrading from 20.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423121/no-sound-in-ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-after-upgrading-from-20-04-lts)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74408508/ubuntu-22-04-no-sound-issue
- [No sound on headphones with sof-hda-dsp audio on ubuntu (and variants)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253498/no-sound-on-headphones-with-sof-hda-dsp-audio-on-ubuntu-and-variants)

Comment: If it is new and came with Ubuntu preinstalled I would send kit back for repair.

Comment: It is a work computer, and IT set it up.  When I got it, it was in the box and Ubuntu was installed, but it had been opened for IT to do some configuration.  It may have once had Windows.  I contacted IT, but it is very hard to get Linux support with them.

Comment: Same answer. Take it to them they built it they should have tested it. The hardware could be bad.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have more or less the same issue on my Samsung Galaxy Notebook II with the 00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01). Bluetooth headphones or connecting an HDMI cable lets me hear sound, but not when trying to use the built in speakers. And no - the hardware is unfortunately not at fault - up until yesterday I had the pre-installed Windows on the laptop and the built-in speakers were flawless...

Comment: I brought it to IT.  They completely wiped the hard drive.  Then the speakers worked, for about the next thirty minutes, before failing again once I re-setup the entire computer.  However, eventually they did work again on their own.  I think it may have been after installing an update.  Currently they work, but create notable echoes on conference calls.