# Accidentally uninstalled GUI when removing Pipewire

Tags: gnome, 22.04, pipewire, yubikey

I was having sound issues ([previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1463481/ubuntu-22-04-no-sound-from-speakers)), and after a lot of reading heard of the much-touted PipeWire.

I followed this helpful guide to [install PipeWire](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-pipewire-on-ubuntu-linux).  This only made things worse, as now even my headphone output was unreliable and usual diagnostic screens only said it was outputting to PipeWire.

I followed the same helpful guide to uninstall PipeWire and revert to alsa-pulse.  This resulted in completely uninstalling gnome, because obviously.

This altered the entire boot process, so that I can no longer log into my computer normally (which requires a yubikey).

I have reinstalled everything (including pipewire, to be safe), but when it tries to authenticate, it hangs indefinitely.  Switching back to the terminal, I can log in (the terminal can read the yubikey), interrupt the hanging process and launch *a* GUI with `startx`.

Is there any way to fix this, to go back to the usual boot process?  All of the GUI parts are reinstalled, the issue is in the login stage when reading from the key.

Output is hard to retrieve, since all the important details are output prior to launching X.

Here is the output, the best I can transcribe, at the relevant failpoint

```
snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: didn't find PCM for DAI Digital Codec DAI
snd-hda-codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: error at snd_soc_dai_startup  on Digital Codec DAI: -22
 Digital Playback and Capture: soc_pcm_open() failed (-22)
 HDA Digital: ASoC: dpcm_be_dai_startup() failed at Digital Playback and Capture (-22)
 HDA Digital dpcm_fe_dai_startup() failed (-22)
snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: didn't find PCM for DAI Digital Codec DAI
snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: error at snd_soc_dai_startup on Digital Codec DAI: -22
 Digital Playback and Capture: soc_pcm_open() failed (-22)
 HDA Digital: ASoC: dpcm_be_dai_startup() failed at Digital Playback and Capture (-22)
 HDA Digital: dpcm_fe_dai_startup() failed (-22)
```

It will sit there indefinitely until I press enter from the command line, at which point I can use the computer through the command line, or type `startx` to launch X server.

Comment: The issue may have been related to [Wayland](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop).  Setting `WaylandEnable=true` allows me to login directly without having to open terminal, though the bootup behavior is still not what it was before (it used to show several more screens and auto-recognize my username from the key)

Answer (score 0):

Login to the console, and assuming you have an internet connection, issue this pair of commands:

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^`

This will re-install the packages you adversely removed.

Comment: Thanks, I had installed without the carrot, tried installing `ubuntu-desktop^`.  However, that did not fix my issue

Comment: Did it install anything? What's the output? Please paste in the question.

Comment: It generates several hundred lines, but the first few hundred are noting which packages it is selection, then the next several hundred are telling me that it is already the newest version.