# No sound on Huawei 14S with Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: sound, alsa, huawei

We bought a Huawei 14S, it pretty nice but there's troubles with sound on speaker and headphones, sometimes headphones don't work, often speaker doesn't work.
It's a nightmare !

Answer (score 0):

It's not a perfect solution, more a workaround :
Sound of speaker works and need to use external adapter for headphones (something like [this one](https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B09SKRKD19))

1 - add this line at bottom of `/etc/modprobe.d/alsabase.conf` :

```
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

2 - reboot

3 - try command `alsactl init`.
Speaker should work (go to sound parameters if not).

4 - if `alsactl init` works, add startup application in gnome :

launch `gnome-session-properties` command and add a new app :

```
name :    Alsactl Init
command : alsactl init
comment : to make speaker work
```

. . save, close and reboot

Speaker should work (go to sound parameters if not).

! Never use the integrated headphones

! Use external usb to jack adapter

PS : The command listed [here](https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/3350#issuecomment-1337839146) might help if still doesn't work (need to install `alsa-tools` package to use `hda-verb` command).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, and based on the materials I found, I wrote a daemon that solves it.

### Problem

The headphone and speaker channels are mixed up in the sound card driver for Linux distributions.

When headphones are connected, the system considers that sound should be output from the speakers. When the headphones are off, the system tries to output sound through them.

#### Problem details (found [here](https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/3350#issuecomment-1301070327))

Looks like there is some weird hardware design, because from my prospective, the interesting widgets are:

- 0x01 - Audio Function Group
- 0x10 - Headphones DAC (really both devices connected here)
- 0x11 - Speaker DAC
- 0x16 - Headphones Jack
- 0x17 - Internal Speaker

And:

- widgets 0x16 and 0x17 simply should be connected to different DACs 0x10 and 0x11, but Internal Speaker 0x17 ignores the connection select command and use the value from Headphones Jack 0x16.
- Headphone Jack 0x16 is controlled with some weird stuff so it should be enabled with GPIO commands for Audio Group 0x01.
- Internal Speaker 0x17 is coupled with Headphone Jack 0x16 so it should be explicitly disabled with EAPD/BTL Enable command.

### Solution

A daemon has been implemented that monitors the connection/disconnection of headphones and accesses the sound card device in order to switch playback to the right place.

You can get installer in my github repo: [huawei-ubuntu-sound-fix](https://github.com/Smoren/huawei-ubuntu-sound-fix).

Hope it helps.